# Audio recording issue android

Tags: android

I have devlope application in which i can record audio and store it in sd card but here raise some problem which i have mention here:: and also confuse in this line `AudioRecorder2 au = new AudioRecorder2("");` is that which path i could set?

**3 rd Update ::**

LOGCAT ::

```
10-25 11:55:07.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751): java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.testAudio.testAudio1.startRecording(testAudio1.java:74)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.testAudio.testAudio1.onRecord(testAudio1.java:31)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.testAudio.testAudio1.access$0(testAudio1.java:29)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.testAudio.testAudio1$RecordButton$1.onClick(testAudio1.java:88)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2179)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:3828)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6291)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3368)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1197)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1993)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1525)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
10-25 11:55:07.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(751):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Main Activity :**

```
package com.testAudio;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class testAudio1 extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public testAudio1() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.testAudio"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".testAudio1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your this exception:

```
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ShaneshRecording.ShaneshRecording in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@435986e0
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
10-25 10:33:21.063: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
10-
```

This exception says that class is missing to load at runtime so i am sure you have defined **`android:name`** attribute in `<application>` tag inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

If you have defined this attribute then remove it and check it again.

Comment: can you please help me to solve i need your few minutes attension

Comment: hi paresh i have try another example with here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html   
now problem raise with start audio playing. i have update my entire code so please check it and tell me what is the problem are raise?

Comment: issue is nothing but first time it is name not define in activity second time when i have tried with android official site example i got error about sycronize of sound but when i surround with try catch it goes success for me

Comment: delete all comments here, it really un-useful for other users